# how to use scanner bufio

Tags: go

Input from `console`

```
12
4.0
```

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
    var in uint64
    var fl float64
    var st string
    // Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
     var str string
    for scanner.Scan() {
          fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
     }
```

How can I use the first value which `12` and add it `4` print that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also have to use strconv to convert a numbers

```
    scn := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    scn.Scan()
    n1, err := strconv.Atoi(scn.Text())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("operation failed: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    scn.Scan()
    n2, err := strconv.Atoi(scn.Text())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("operation failed: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d + %d = %d\n", n1, n2, n1+n2)
```